# Explain steps RedHat distros take to boot into Emergency mode?

Tags: linux, kernel, startup, init

Please, I am not looking for a rehash of what's stated in [RedHat's documentation](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/custom-guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-emergency.html) regarding emergency mode. I would like to know what steps are involved from the time grub hands off to the kernel to the time you get a emergency mode login prompt.

I imagine /sbin/init is completely bypassed and therefore rc.sysinit bypassed as well. I don't however know what isn't bypassed or how emergency mode differs (intimately) with init=/bin/sh.

What sort of steps does the kernel take when given the emergency argument at boot time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal situation:

1. bios initialization
2. bootloader
3. kernel initialization
4. init starts and enters your runlevel & execute:

   - /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit
   - /etc/rc.d/rc and /etc/rc.d/rc?.d/
   - /etc/rc.d/rc.local
5. X display manager

In emergency mode you bypass 'rc.sysinit' and runs only 'sulogin'
script by default. To see what is happening on your system see /etc/inittab.

Comment: That's mostly what I was looking for, now I know emergency mode is passed as an argument to /sbin/init. Thanks! What is the boot process when you pass init=/bin/sh to the kernel on boot? I imagine the kernel no longer calls /sbin/init and instead calls /bin/sh. Is this correct?

Comment: I tested my assumption regarding init=/bin/sh by passing init=/sbin/init. The system booted as normal so I imagine that init=/bin/sh does in fact cause the kernel to execute sh in place of init, versus as some sort of argument to init or something else.

Comment: Yes, one of last things kernel initialization does is invoke execve() on the argument you pass to it by init=whatever if it fails it tries to run init from several locations if that fails you end up with /bin/sh.

Answer (score 1):

No scripts are processed and you are given a root shell.  Requires a password. Uses PAM if configured.

Comment: Not telling me anything I don't already know, but that doesn't make your answer any less correct. Thanks.